# Four Fundamental Spaces Question

Tags: linear-algebra

Why do the four fundamental sub spaces come from **Ax=b** and **A'y=f**? Why these two equations?

Answer (score 1):

The first key observation is that if $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)'$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$ are two column vectors then 
$$x'y=x_1y_1+x_2y_2+...+x_ny_n=:x\cdot y$$
which is the standard scalar product.

The second key observation is that if $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, and $z=(z_1,z_2,...,z_m)'$  is a column vector of dimension $m$, then

$$(Ax)\cdot y=x\cdot (A'y)$$

The four spaces get related in this equation. If $x\in\text{Ker}(A)$ then $Ax=0$. Therefore from the equation above $$x\cdot(A'y)=(Ax)\cdot y=0\cdot y=0$$

from where we see that $x$ is orthogonal to $A'y$ for all $y$. This shows that $\text{Ker}(A)$ is orthogonal to $\text{Im}(A')$. Other relations follow similarly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this article has what you are looking for:

http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Essays/newpaper_ver3.pdf

It goes into detail about the four subspaces commonly studied in Linear Algebra courses, that is, the column and null spaces of the matrices $A$ and $A^T$.